# I failed to rewrite the boost::asio tutorial with the networking ts. What's wrong with my code?

Tags: c++, networking, boost-asio

I tried to make a networking TS version of this tutorial:
https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_75_0/doc/html/boost_asio/tutorial/tutdaytime2/src.html

First, I compiled and ran the boost version, and it works fine.

Then I wrote this:

```
#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#include <experimental/net>
namespace net = std::experimental::net;

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
std::string make_daytime_string()
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
{
 time_t now = std::time(0);
 const std::string result = std::ctime(&now);
 std::cout << "sending: " << result << '\n';
 return result;
}

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
int main()
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
{
 try
 {
  net::io_context io_context;

  net::ip::tcp::acceptor acceptor
  (
   io_context,
   net::ip::tcp::endpoint(net::ip::tcp::v4(), 8013)
  );

  while (true)
  {
   net::ip::tcp::socket socket(io_context);
   acceptor.accept(io_context);
   net::write(socket, net::buffer(make_daytime_string()));
  }
 }
 catch (std::exception& e)
 {
  std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
 }

 return 0;
}
```

I am using the implementation of the networking ts available there:
https://github.com/chriskohlhoff/networking-ts-impl

I am doing this in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, compiling with gcc.

The server code compiles, and runs. But as soon as a client makes a connection, it fails with this exception:

```
write: Bad file descriptor
```

, and the client does not receive anything. My code looks really equivalent to the asio one. Why does it fail?

Answer (score 3):

```
   net::ip::tcp::socket socket(io_context);
   acceptor.accept(io_context);
```

You're discarding the connected socket (and redundantly constructing one from the execution context that you already pass to `accept` anyways).

Fix it with

```
    auto socket = acceptor.accept(io_context);
```